# What factors should I consider when downsizing equipment - and getting rid of a camera?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

This is an inverse shopping question really.. rather what equipment should I buy.. what equipment should I get rid of, and how to decide.

Currently I have one full frame camera (5D2), and one crop sensor camera (7D). I've just placed an order for a new FF DSLR (5D4) which will leave me three cameras.

- Both existing bodies have their own pros and cons, e.g. AF/FPS, lowlight, image quality, full framey goodness.
- I use both my existing bodies for different purposes, however I expect the new one will take over all purposes as has all the pros of both my existing cameras.
- I do double body
- No. Really. I don't need three cameras!

What should I look at (including my existing work) to decide which one to get rid of?

(I'm trying to keep this generic and on topic as much as possible, so if you can provide comments for alterations/changes to bring this on topic please do!)

Bit more detailed stuff: 95+% of my work is fashion (studio and location) and live music.

When I use one camera (so the fashion work) I tend to use the 5D2 over the 7D because the image quality is far superior. HOWEVER if I just need to grab a camera, e.g. if i'm going away for the weekend I tend to take the 7D due to better straight from camera images (IMHO).

I double body whilst shooting the live music work, using a mid range zoom and a slightly longer zoom. The 5D gives me better low light performance. However the 7D gives me better FPS and auto focus. (The 5D4 should give me the best of both worlds and I expect will end up becoming my goto cam).

I find I rarely need the extra reach, and if I do I have an extender.

Comment: Thoughts I'd had include: see which one I get the most money for to offset expenditure of new camera, which of the two bodies I use the most, existing lens compatability.

Comment: The 3 bodies in question might actually of benefit here, to understand what pros and cons you are likely contemplating.

Comment: @AthomSfere I was trying to keep as generic as possible, but will edit.

Comment: Understood, and generally that's great. For this question though I think it's too broad (And I must not be the only one) Also I see your edits, and I'd say that's good! The emphasis isn't the bodies but gives us some context.

Comment: DV'er rather than just downvote could you provide some feedback please?

Comment: @AthomSfere I could make it extremely detailed, but then it wouldn't have much relevance to anyone else.

Comment: I'd get rid of the 5D2 and keep the cropped. Reason for me is wild life photos, where the cropping will give some virtual extra range (at the loss of picture information). [On the other hand, if you drop the 5D4, you'd still have a FF backup with the 5D2]

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr [Please answer in answers, not comments](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/please-put-your-answers-in-the-answers-section-even-if-theyre-short).

Comment: @PhilipKendall I considered this rather an opinion of an amateur, than a valid answer

Comment: The entire question is opinion based. *Any answer* can only be an opinion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For me, the first and most important question to figure out would be the same as when buying new stuff - **why** do you need that second body. If you only had the 5D4, why would you be looking to buy that second camera? Not selling something means you value it more than the money, same as buying it. Nail down your intent, and the solution often becomes obvious.

For example, if you're keeping one as a backup body, neither of the old cameras is ideal for every situation. But hey, you haven't had an ideal backup camera so far either. So, you could try to figure out which one would be more beneficial in your most critical scenarios. You might even consider selling both and ordering another 5D4, but this really depends on your intent - how important is having a backup body vs. how much do you need the cash. If backup camera is just something nice to have, sell the one that brings in more cash.

Intend to have a spare body with crop-factor tele abilities and a matching viewfinder? Obvious.

Intend to prance around on dark streets with two cameras proudly dangling on your neck? Obvious.

Intend to shoot weddings? Two bodies is bare minimum for having different lenses ready to shoot, three is where you'd actually have one as a backup.

Comment: This is pretty on the mark! I am planning on a pair of 5D4s in the future but not for a while.

Answer (score 7):

As I usually recommend to try several cameras how they fit askers hands/mind when asking what to buy my answer will be very simillar.

You dont't have the 5D mk4 at the time. Keep all three for a while and trace what body you are using the most and what body you are using the least.

When there is significant difference between #2 and #3 go sell "the loser" because you actually dont need it. If the difference is negligible, you have found the use for all your cameras and you actually benefit from having three.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to:

I'd get rid of the 5D2 and keep the cropped.

Reason for me is wild life photos, where the cropping will give some virtual extra range (at the loss of picture information).

So it basically depends on your need, which to keep and which to drop.

[On the other hand, if you drop the 5D4, you'd still have a FF backup with the 5D2]